# imblearn's Pipeline.fit_resample() with "passthrough" last step returns only transformed X?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

Is there a particular reason for `imblearn.Pipeline`'s `fit_resample` to only return `Xt` and not `yt` when the last step is `"passthrough"`? I was expecting it to return both `X` and `y` resampled.

(See the [**source code snippet**](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/0a659af54c3b97969ea23ff22a8eebff3696d069/imblearn/pipeline.py#L521-L522))

I wonder if this could be a bug, since it breaks the standard `Xt, yt` return value of `fit_resample` specified in the [user guide](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/introduction.html#api-s-of-imbalanced-learn-samplers) (if there is indeed such a standard).

Is there some simple explanation that I am not aware of, such as compatibility with `sklearn`'s API or something like that? I could not find other notes or GH issues regarding this, but it seemed reasonable to post here before opening an issue in case I am missing something.

**Edit:** I just noticed that the method's docstring (see the linked source code) makes no mention to possibly returning a single object, simply listing `Xt` and `yt` as return values, which seems to corroborate this being some sort of bug.